# Local development setup for python with docker

Tags: python, docker

I am starting a new python project and considering Docker for local development and shipping the application. I am particularly looking for supporting local setup for development where container OS is different than the host OS.

Generally, I have a local virtual environment where I have all the dependencies isolated for the app. Now creating a virtual environment inside docker would override the host environment but it allows me to persist env changes across container boots.

So my options are:

1. Use virtual env in the host for management tasks and container system env inside the container. This allows users to run management tasks on the host. But this requires them to install dependencies twice (once on the host and other in the container). Moreover, the container changes will be lost on the next reboot and they have to do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` on every container boot.
2. Don't have any environment on the host and create a virtual env inside the container persisting to the project directory. This removes the duplicate work but now the local files on the host may not be compatible with the system it resides on.
3. Have a host virtual env and container virtual env which is persisted to a volume. This requires duplicate work on the developer end but the persistence issue is now gone.

I would like to know if there are other options, what workflow/setup is recommended and has worked out in the wild.

Comment: You are talking about host and containers. But building images should be the important part of your solution.

Comment: You can use [VSCode Remote container](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/07/01/containers-wsl), and mounting the source code volume on container.

Comment: have you used pipenv?